# What does second number in "POST /myfunction/ HTTP/1.1" 200 23" mean?

Tags: python, django, http, pycharm

I am trying to debug my django code in pycharm3,

I notice that when I run a request I see the following in the run window:

```
Django version 1.6.1, using settings 'driver1.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[19/Mar/2014 11:14:05] "POST /myfunction/ HTTP/1.1" 200 23
```

I know that 200 is the HTTP status code for 'OK', but what is '23'?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second value describes the length in bytes your reponse had. Sometimes you'll see an third value - this is the total time in seconds your response took.

So your request to `/myfunction/` responded  an HTTP status 'OK' and the data returned had 23 byte in its length.

Comment: Thanks, That makes sense. Is there a way to configure the request to show the third value? That would be really useful to know. Thanks again, - Bill

Comment: As far as I know there's no way to increase the verbosity of django's built-in development server to show the response time.

Comment: Thanks, I may put this out as a question.